# MySQL PHP: WHERE everything except

Tags: php, mysql

How can  in a query,

```
SELECT * WHERE type =
```

is everything except "news"? Or should i check that later in the while()?

Comment: Start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_operator#Standard_relational_operators Hint: The one you need is on the second row of the table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE type != 'news';
```

Is one way, if you have multiple:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE type NOT IN('news', 'other');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE type != 'news'
```

Answer (score 1):

`` `SELECT * FROM atable WHERE type != 'news' ``

Leave as much querying as you can to the database, that's what they are for!

Answer (score 1):

The ANSI answer would be
    SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE type <> 'news'

!= is not the good inequality operator in SQL. 'NOT LIKE' without using wildcards is the exact same thing as the <> operator. NOT IN is also the best solutions if you have to check the equality (or inequality) for many strings.

P.S. I would rather post this as a comment, but I'm afraid I don't totally understand StackOverflow yet, I can't do this yet (or I don't have enough reputation to comment).

Answer (score -2):

It's actually

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE type NOT LIKE 'news'